# Connection string using a shared network from a batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, connection-string

I am trying to run some R code launched from a batch file. The R code pulls information from an Access database using the `odbcDriverConnect` function in the `RODBC` library. The R code works if I launch it inside R, but if I try to call the code from a batch file, the code fails.

The problem, I believe, is that the connection string for the ODBC call points to a shared network, which would be unmapped when running the batch file. I have tried to use the UNC path (not supported in batch files?) and tried using `pushd` in the batch file to temporarily map the drive that I need. Neither option has worked successfully. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

For simplicity, I currently have the batch and R code stored on my local `C:` drive, with the only item on the shared network drive the Access database being called in R.

The (anonymized) batch code and R code are copied below. Thanks!

Batch:

```
pushd \\Server\Path
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Testing\r_test.R"
```

R:

```
library(RODBC)
accessDB <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
    DBQ=Z:/Path/Database.accdb")
```

Comment: UNC paths are supported in batch files and many if not most of the batch commands, but you have to be connected to that share. It doesn't have to be mapped to a drive letter. See `net help use`.  If memory serves me right `net use <UNC>` should do it for you.

Comment: I am still not clear exactly what your problem statement is. Please [edit] your post and include the errors you are seeing or some statement indicating what you mean by "the code fails".

Comment: Also, take the [tour], read [Ask], and (for good measure) [MCVE].